# Como remover o título de um Custom Dialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

Tenho este Custom Dialog
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria de saber como tirar essa parte do título porque neste caso, ela é desnecessária.

Código

```
private void acertou() {


    final Dialog certo = new Dialog(this);
    certo.setContentView(R.layout.resultado_positivo);

    Button okPositivo = (Button) certo.findViewById(R.id.okPositivo);

    okPositivo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View e) {

            dinheiro +=600;
            actualizarRecompensa();

            certo.dismiss();

        }

    });

    certo.show();

}
```

E o no XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_dialogos"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Correcto!!!"
        android:id="@+id/txtcerto"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/okPositivo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/seleccionador"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtcerto"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Como está a construir o dialog? Coloque o código.

Comment: Aí está o código (editei a pergunta). O XML e o código no Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No arquivo `/res/values/styles.xml` declare um *style* acrescentado estas linhas:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Use esse *style* ao criar o *dialog*:

```
final Dialog certo = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Outra possibilidade é usar `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`

```
final Dialog certo = new Dialog(this);
certo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```